# Cannot validate el-select elementUI

Tags: validation, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to create custom validation with el-select such way :

In my template :

```
 <el-form ref="form" >
<el-form-item   prop="fieldProp" >
    <el-select class="dialog-select" v-model="informationForm.age"  @change="validateDropdown" 
    placeholder="age" style="width: 100%"  >
      <el-option label="11" value="1"></el-option>
      <el-option label="22" value="2"></el-option>
    </el-select>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

In data :

```
   data() {
        let  checkCurrency = (rule, value, callback) => {
            if (!value) {
                return callback(new Error('Please input the age'));
            }
        };
        return {
                fieldProp: [
                    { validator: checkCurrency, trigger: 'change' }
                ]
              }
         }
```

In my methods:

```
validateDropdown() {
            this.$refs.form.validateField('fieldProp')
        }
```

And calling the validation method : in submit

```
   submit() {
            this.validateDropdown(); 
        }
```

But nothing happens. Any idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to read the element ui doc about (custom) form validation : https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form#custom-validation-rules

In your case you should add a `model` and `rules` prop to your form and then use the proper `validate` method.

Example code :

```
<el-form ref="form" :model="informationForm" :rules="rules">
  <el-form-item prop="age" >
    <el-select class="dialog-select" v-model="informationForm.age" placeholder="age" style="width: 100%">
      <el-option label="11" value="1"></el-option>
      <el-option label="22" value="2"></el-option>
    </el-select>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>
```

```
   data() {
        let  checkCurrency = (rule, value, callback) => {
            if (!value) {
                return callback(new Error('Please input the age'));
            }
        };
        return {
          rules: {
            fieldProp: [
              { required: true, validator: checkCurrency, trigger: 'change' }
            ]
          }
        }
   }
```

No need for `validateDropdown` because your field is already validate on each `change` thanks to this : `trigger: 'change'`.

```
submit() {
  this.$refs.form.validate((valid) => {
    if (valid) {
      // todo
    } else {
      // todo
    }
  });
}
```